# Not able to show Line shape on ContentPresenter in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to display different shapes on Content Presenter in wpf, I am able to show Rectangle but Line object is not getting populated, Can anyone help me with this

```
 Line r = new Line();
        r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 50.0);
        r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10.0);
        r.X1 = 50;
        r.Y1 = 50;
        r.X2 = 150;
        r.Y2 = 150;
        r.Width = 200;
        r.StrokeThickness = 5.0;
        r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        ContentComponent.Content = r;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `Stroke` property to a `Brush`:

```
r.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
```

Note that there is no reason to create a new green brush using `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)` instead of using the static `Green` property of the `Brushes` class.

Comment: Tried with Stroke Green, still it is not visible

Comment: @SriSiddu: Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue then. Is `ContentComponent` visible? What if you set its `Content` property to something else?